# Why do a div and a table behave differently when given width=100% here?

Tags: html, padding, css

Here's my code, reduced to the relevant parts:

```
<html><head><title></title>
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color: #fff; }
#titlebar{ border: solid 1px black; margin:10px; }

#bodyWrapper{ float: left; width: 100%; }

#bodyColumn{ margin-left: 230px; height:500px; }

#menuColumn{
    float: left;
    width: 230px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin-left: -100%;
    height:500px;
}

.bigContent{ width: 100%; margin:10px; }

.section{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding:10px;
    overflow: auto;
}
</style></head><body>

<div id="titlebar">Title</div>
<div id="bodyWrapper"><div id="bodyColumn">

<table class="section bigContent"><tr><td>FIRST</td></table></table>
<div class="section bigContent">SECOND</div>

</div></div>
<div id="menuColumn">MENU</div>
</body></html>
```

My problem:

- The `<div>` containing "SECOND" is wider than the `<table>` containing "FIRST" although both are siblings and have `width=100%` via the same CSS class
- The `<div>` is also wider than the screen, causing scrollbars to appear

Why is this and what can I do to fix it?

Note: I am seeing the same problems in both Firefox 3.6 and IE 8

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of the `padding`. In CSS, the width property applies to the content box of elements, without the padding.

See http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html : The `width` property applies to the `Content` block in the following schema:

[image]

So the outer element's width is 100% of the parent's width, plus 10px of left padding and 10px of right padding.

Given that this element is a block element, it should not be necessary to specify its width to 100%.

So the solutions are:

- To not set a width
- To take the padding into account when setting the width (here this would require to set the padding in `%`, e.g. 2% of padding and a width of 96% (100-2*2)

Comment: This doesn't explain why `<table>` doesn't behave like this.

Comment: I think the `padding` property doesn't apply to a `<table>` tag directly; so the table itself has no padding and this does not affects it.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it. I've just wrapped my table in a div and left off the width and it works. Good to know for the future, too.